# How does c# remove the memory allocated in loop?

Tags: c#

imagine this code:

```
int i=9999999;
while ( i > 1 )
{
    string UnusedMemory="this is a string that eats some ram" + i.ToString();
    i--;
}
```

if unreferenced objects were removed only sometimes when `GC.Collect()` is run, this code should allocate lot of ram until collect happen. But it doesn't allocate huge memory at all, why? Is there some kind of "delete" implemented on IL level? Or is `GC.Collect()` called automatically faster? I know this is a trivial example, but if it was more complicated and string was accessed in that block of code, it wouldn't eat lot of ram anyway.

EDIT: I changed the example so that string is always unique, so that it can't be "cached"

Comment: Because the UnusedMemory variable is defined inside the loop it is only valid for each iteration. After each iteration UnusedMemory is GCd... I believe, it wont retain it

Comment: @craig1231 so you think that GC is called everytime after each iteration? Isn't that CPU expensive?

Comment: @Petr GC is not called at each iteration. `UnusedMemory` is discarded (actually it probably isn't because it can be reused), but the string itself is a reference type so it just floats around without any references and it is collected at some point when GC sets in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String constants are "cached" in a string pool, so it's the same string each time.

If you use the method `String.IsInterned` on the string, then it will return `true` which means it's contained in the pool.

From [String.IsInterned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned.aspx):

> The common language runtime automatically maintains a table, called
>   the intern pool, which contains a single instance of each unique
>   literal string constant declared in a program, as well as any unique
>   instance of String you add programmatically.
>
> The intern pool conserves string storage. If you assign a literal
>   string constant to several variables, each variable is set to
>   reference the same constant in the intern pool instead of referencing
>   several different instances of String that have identical values.

Furthermore, the GC is automatically called when memory are needed or enough elements have been allocated, so even if strings weren't cached then it wouldn't be a problem.

From [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx):

Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:

- The system has low physical memory.
- **The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This means that a threshold of acceptable memory usage has been exceeded on the managed heap. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.**
- The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

**Is it possible to change this behavior or optimize it?**
Yes, to some extend: [Latency Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx)

This question is very much related to:
[C# memory usage for creating objects in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794985/c-sharp-memory-usage-for-creating-objects-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: ok, can you elaborate a bit on "if enough elements" how many elements is enough? How does GC know when it should or not remove them? Is it possible to change this behavior or optimize it?

Comment: @Petr I don't think you can get an exact answer on when enough is enough, but you can optimize the behavior with the link I added. "How does GC know when it should or not remove them?" The basics are explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx in the section "What happens..." and if you want to know more details look at http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/slides/45a-garbagecollection.pdf

Answer (score 3):

When an object is allocated from the heap, and there isn't enough free space, the garbage collector will run. If a collection of the first heap doesn't free enough memory it will continue to do collections on the next level heap. Only if collection of all heaps doesn't release enough memory, it will allocate more memory from the system.

As there are a lot of recently freed objects in your example, the collection of the first heap will always free enough memory. Your loop will fill the heap several times. You can print out `GC.CollectionCount(0)` before and after the loop to see how many times it did run.